# Command line input in C gives error and works only for specific case

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// this code take input in cmd line , finds any integer input 
// and stores in an array


int main (int argc,char *argv[]){

    int intput[argc];
    char * frstr = argv[0];
    frstr=frstr+2; //removes ./ from filename while printing
    printf("%s ",frstr);
    int j=0; 

    for(int i = 1;i<argc;i++) //loop to find integers and store in array intput
    {   
        if( atoi(argv[i])>0)
        {   j++;
            intput[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
        }
        printf(" %s ",argv[i]);
    }
     printf("\n ");
    for (int i= 1; i<=j;++i )  // loop to print integers stored in intput
    {

        printf(" %d ",intput[i]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code to take input from cmd line and store any integer input in an array. This works fine if the cmd line inputs are all number but goes haywire as soon as any string input is there. Please help

Comment: `atoi()` is probably not the best choice. [strtol()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) has better diagnostic for this task. (I.e. you have an option to recognize whether it failed at all.)

Comment: "goes haywire" is not a problem description. What exactly happens? Are you checking for failure properly/enough?

Comment: `i <= j` should be `i < j`

Comment: @underscore_d "haywire" presumably means it's printing total garbage because it's accessing an uninitialized array element.

Comment: You've probably realized this, but: the program will wrongly skip any number 0 on the command line.  That's because there's no good way to know whether `atoi` succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
intput[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

You use `j` to keep track of the number of elements in `intput`, but you're using `i` (which is the current element number `argv`) instead.  You want:

```
intput[j] = atoi(argv[i]);
```